# Ubuntu installation: restart doesn't work but shutdown works

Tags: boot, 16.04, shutdown

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS version using a bootable usb. It has given me a lot of grief.

Earlier it was not showing me the login screen, I resolved it by disabling secure boot option in the BIOS.

Now, the os is not restarting, whenever I click on restart it gets stuck. However, shutdown is working perfectly.

**EDIT**

1. Following command doesn't work, the machine hangs after executing the command:

   sudo reboot
2. Even `ctrl + alt + F1` doesn't work on the login screen, it doesn't show me the console.
3. I cannot even `logout` from the system.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please try to reboot with `sudo reboot` and `dbus-send --print-reply --system --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart`? What happens when you do that? Please [edit] your question to explain what you did and what happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following command to resolve all the issues:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```